# Iterating a multi-dimensional object with es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Are there any methods on how can I iterate between object keys

```
var dataSubmit = {
email : {
  value : email,
  rules : 'required email'
},
password : {
  value : password,
  rules : 'required,min:6'
}
```

};

I was hoping I can access it like

```
each (data in dataSubmit) {
 console.log(data.value);
 console.log(data.rules);
}
```

and get

```
 email: {value : email, rules : 'required, email'};
```

so I can

```
iterator {
  func(email: {value : email, rules : 'required, email'})
}
```

I need to keep the object as whole

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there, use the [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) statement for that - replace `each` with `for`.

```js
var dataSubmit = {
  email : {
    value : 'email',
    rules : 'required email'
  },
  password : {
    value : 'password',
    rules : 'required,min:6'
  }
};

for (let key in dataSubmit) {
  console.log(dataSubmit[key]);
}
```

Alternatively use the [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) statement with `Object.values(dataSubmit)` which returns an array of values

```js
var dataSubmit = {
  email : {
    value : 'email',
    rules : 'required email'
  },
  password : {
    value : 'password',
    rules : 'required,min:6'
  }
};

for (let data of Object.values(dataSubmit)) {
  console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this

Answer (score 3):

```
for(const data of Object.values(dataSubmit)) 
  console.log(data.value, data.rules);
```

Just use `for..of` on the objects values.

Comment: Thank you for this

Answer (score 1):

You could use `forEach` loop on `Object.values`.

```js
var dataSubmit = {email: {value: "email",rules: 'required email'},password: {value: "password",rules: 'required,min:6'}};

Object.values(dataSubmit).forEach(o => {
  console.log(o.value);
  console.log(o.rules)
})
```